# Changing values in a row until value is not null or >1 with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change values in a row until the value is >1

I have a data set as the following:

```
       Week1  week 2  week 3
Value   0      0       1
Value   0      1       2
```

I want to switch out the zero to a null until the row becomes grater than 0.

How would I be able to write that in pandas?

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with code, what you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with 2 boolean masks chained by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
print (df)
       Week 1  week 2  week 3  week 4  week 5
Value       0       0       1       0       1
Value       0       1       2       0       1

df = df.mask(df.gt(1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0) & df.eq(0), np.nan)
print (df)
       Week 1  week 2  week 3  week 4  week 5
Value     NaN     NaN       1     NaN       1
Value     NaN     1.0       2     0.0       1
```

**Details**:

Compare by [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) `(>)`:

```
print (df.gt(1))
       Week 1  week 2  week 3  week 4  week 5
Value   False   False   False   False   False
Value   False   False    True   False   False
```

Use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) for check find values until first `False` per row:

```
print (df.gt(1).cumsum(axis=1))
       Week 1  week 2  week 3  week 4  week 5
Value       0       0       0       0       0
Value       0       0       1       1       1
```

Compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) `(==)`:

```
print (df.gt(1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0))
       Week 1  week 2  week 3  week 4  week 5
Value    True    True    True    True    True
Value    True    True   False   False   False
```

Compare original data:

```
print (df.eq(0))
       Week 1  week 2  week 3  week 4  week 5
Value    True    True   False    True   False
Value    True   False   False    True   False
```

Chain together:

```
print (df.gt(1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(0) & df.eq(0))
       Week 1  week 2  week 3  week 4  week 5
Value    True    True   False    True   False
Value    True   False   False   False   False
```